# How can I enable CloudWatch logging on an API Gateway v2 API via Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws

I would like to enable execution logging on an `aws_apigatewayv2_api` resource. I can simply click the below checkbox to do so.

Since I know it is possible via AWS GUI, what is the terraform equivalent?

I already have logging enabled on each individual integration lambda, but this checkbox stays unchecked.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This setting is on the stage itself i.e. [`aws_apigatewayv2_stage`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_stage) under the [`default_route_settings`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/apigatewayv2_stage#default_route_settings) argument.

To replicate the UI:

- *Enable CloudWatch Logs* & *Log level* - these 2 options are combined in Terraform under `logging_level`. Logging is disabled by default as `logging_level` is set to `OFF`. To enable logging, you will need to simply specify the `logging_level` to any other supported value other than `OFF`, which has the effect of turning logging on & setting the level at the same time.
- *Log full message data* - this is in Terraform under `detailed_metrics_enabled`.

This results in the below config:

```
resource "aws_apigatewayv2_stage" "example" {
  api_id = aws_apigatewayv2_api.example.id
  name   = "example-stage"
  default_route_settings {
    logging_level = "INFO"
    detailed_metrics_enabled = true
  }
}
```

Comment: An argument named "default_route_settings" is not expected here. Did you mean to define a block of type "default_route_settings"?

Comment: @devteamatl ah sorry, minor typo - fixed  glad you got it fixed.